# Do i really need to include table names or AS in JOINS if columns are different?

Tags: mysql, join, syntax

I noticed te other day I can joins in mysql just as easily by doing,

```
 SELECT peeps, persons, friends FROM tablea JOIN tableb USING (id) WHERE id = ?
```

In stead of using,

```
 SELECT a.peeps, a.persons, b.friends FROM tablea a JOIN tableb b USING (id) WHERE id = ?
```

It only works if there is no matching column names, why should I do the second rather than the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query 1 will work (as long as there are no ambiguous column names).

Query 2 will

- be clearer
- be more maintainable (think of someone who doesn't know the database schema by heart)
- survive the addition of an ambiguous column name to one of the tables

So, don't be lazy because of that pitiful few saved keystrokes.

Comment: @cgwebprojects: We all are, but this special kind of laziness is usually coming back to bite you at some time.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't *need* to, but in my humble opinion you really **should**.  It's almost always better in my experience to be explicit with what you're trying to do.

Consider the feelings of the poor guy (or girl) who has to come behind you and try to figure out what you were trying to accomplish and in which tables each column resides.  Explicitly stating the source of the column allows one to look at the query and glean that information without deep knowledge of the schema.

Comment: Thanks never thought about that!

Comment: An additional point here - queries often expand and grow from simple ones like above. Getting in the habit of always using prefixes makes your life easier when you need to expand a query.  Similarly, when a tableB is modified and now contains a column with the same name as tableA you don't have to go back to this query/procedure/view and add aliasing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary if you have no duplicate column names. If you do, the query will fail.